# How can I fix Ubuntu not detecting my internal Bluetootth Interface Card?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, asus, bluez, detect

I am new on AskUbuntu. I would like to ask if anybody has evere encountered and fixed my same problem. I have an ASUS N56JN and I am dualbooting Ubuntu with Windows10. Windows is correctly working with my Bluettoth Card while Ubuntu can't see the card (and cannot turn on and off the Bluetooth, of course). I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to install some packages like Bluez but nothing seems to fix the issue. If some one has some ideas on how to proceed, thank you!

## Edit

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. ASUS USB2.0 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 25a7:fa61 Compx 2.4G Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the command `dmesg | grep -i blue` is void

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Edited as requested. Thank you!